# How many watts will the resistor in this naîve PSU dissipate?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, resistors, ac, power-dissipation

One would be inclined to think the average current on resistor R would be exactly the same as in the load L, but I'm not so sure of that fact, due to the effect of the (big, 1000uF+) capacitors. During a significant portion of the AC cycle, the current supplying the load comes from the second capacitor, not the resistor.

[image]

What are the calculations involved to assess R's wattage? (Oh, and apologies for the pathetic drawing.)

Comment: I am 47 years old and I want to assemble a PSU for an old PSU-less Apple //c I bought cheap off eBay. Also, I don't have any children of appropriate age for that question. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: The schematic is actually making my eyes hurt. You've created the Comic Sans of schematic capture.

Comment: It took me a good half minute to figure out that the thing in the middle was a bridge rectifier and not some crazy Christmas ornament.

Comment: The voltage over R will change with I, which means that the voltage over L will change with the power usage of L. This seems like a bad characteristic for a power supply. Did you consider using a regulator instead of the resistor?

Answer (score 1):

The current through R will be the sum of the current through the second filter cap and the load.

To calculate R's wattage, it would be the voltage across R times this current.

Comment: ...squared, of course.

Comment: No, I did W = I * V above so there's no square. You can also do I^2*R if that's what you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

After powering on, and the big cap has charged, there will be no "extra" power dissipated in the resistor.  If the second cap supplies current during part of the AC cycle, it will be recharged during the other part of the cycle, through R, so the net effect is the same as if you didn't consider the cap in the first place.